# Handle inconsistent date format string conversion to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, date, type-conversion

Would like to make a conversion to `DateTime` from the following strings of `datetime` format:

```
"3/20/2017 4:03:03 PM"
"03/20/2017 4:03:03 PM"
"3/20/2017 04:03:03 PM"
"03/20/2017 04:03:03 PM"
etc
```

Been using try `DateTime.ParseExact` with the format `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` but `Format Exception` is caught, Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just provide all possible formats to `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: Have you tried just using `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`? I *think* they cope with optional leading zeroes... (And are your days potentially single-digit too?)

Comment: Yes, the days potentially is single-digit too.

Comment: @JonSkeet is right, "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt" seems to handle all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse dates passing all custom Formats in an array:

```
string[] strDates = new string[]{"3/20/2017 4:03:03 PM"
                    ,"03/20/2017 4:03:03 PM"
                    ,"3/20/2017 04:03:03 PM"
                    ,"03/20/2017 04:03:03 PM"};

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string[] strFormats = new string[] { "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt","MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" };
foreach (var item in strDates)
{
    foreach (var format in strFormats)
    {
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact(item, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Or pass the array directly:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(item, strFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work

```
string dateString, format;  
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
dateString = "3/20/2017 4:03:03 PM";
format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";

  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```